# Unmarshall PubSub Request Data []bytes with Go

Tags: json, go, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an end-point that receives data from a Google PubSub request. As per [this repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/docs/managed_vms/pubsub/pubsub.go), the object is as so:

```
type pushRequest struct {
    Message struct {
        Attributes map[string]string
        Data       []byte
        ID         string `json:"message_id"`
    }
    Subscription string
}
```

The Data field is consistently formatted as so:

```
type Data struct {
    Key  string                 `json:"key"`
    Body string                 `json:"body"`
    Meta map[string]interface{} `json:"meta"`
}
```

I can obviously unmarshal the JSON request with something like this:

```
f := &pushRequest{}
json.Unmarshal(msg, &f)
```

That leaves with the the `[]bytes` field. Which I can do something like this to convert to a string, as per the docs

```
messages = append(messages, string(f.Message.Data))
```

Which doesn't help, since I need it as a struct.

I can Unmarshal the array again:

```
var m Data
json.Unmarshal(f.Message.Data, &m)
```

Have tried changing the field type in the `pushRequest` struct to Data without success. Blank...

Is there a way I can unpack things in a single pass? Doing it twice seems ridiculous.

If it's obvious, I just can't see it!

Comment: Can you show the json you are trying to unmarshal?

Comment: Did you try to embed the `Data struct` in the `Message struct`? Or if it's a sub-document, try to change type of `Data` field from `[]byte` to `Data struct`.

Comment: I did try that without success. That's what confused me

Answer (score 1):

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
psmsg := &PushRequest{}
decoderErr := decoder.Decode(&psmsg)

if decoderErr != nil {
    // Error... 
    return
}

data := Data{}
unmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(psmsg.Message.Data)), &data)

if unmarshalErr != nil {
    // Error...
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from my cloud function, which serves as a pub/sub push endpoint. The key is that you first have to decode the body using the `PushRequest` struct. Next, you can transform the message data into a struct. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage), the `Data` field within `Message` is a base-64 encoded string, therefore you have to decode it first.

```
type PushRequest struct {
    Message      pubsub.PubsubMessage `json:"message"`
    Subscription string               `json:"subscription"`
}

type Example struct {
    ID string `json:"id" firestore:"id"`
}

func HTTPEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var pr common.PushRequest
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&pr); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not decode body: %v", err)
        return
    }

    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(pr.Message.Data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Base64: %v", err)
        return
    }

    var example Example
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &example); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Json: %v", err)
        return
    }

    // Do something useful with the struct
}
```